# Kotlin way of filtering max values from 2 arrays?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I currently have 2 arrays, both containing 5 objects. All objects contain `Int` variables.

Sample data:

```
data class Demo(val number: Int, val name: String)

val a = Demo(12, "a")
val b = Demo(1, "b")
val c = Demo(3, "c")
val d = Demo(5, "d")
val e = Demo(17, "e")

val array1 = arrayOf(a,b,c,d,e)

val f = Demo(3, "f")
val g = Demo(8, "g")
val h = Demo(15, "h")
val i = Demo(16, "i")
val j = Demo(22, "j")

val array2 = arrayOf(f,g,h,i,j)

//val array3 = ??
```

What I'm trying to do is create a function which will filter these arrays on the maximum values. Now I know Kotlin has a method on their array called `max()` which will return the maximum value of the array it is used on.

This made me wonder (currently I'm using nested for-loop just like someone would in Java.), is there a <s>visually beautiful</s> faster/better way of doing so in Kotlin?

Expected output using sample data:

```
array3[22,17,16,15,12]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would like to have the 5 bigger int of the two arrays?

```
(array1 + array2).sortedArrayDescending().take(5)
// [22, 17, 16, 15, 12]
```

***With edited answer:***

```
(array1 + array2).sortedByDescending { it.number }.take(5)
// [Demo(number=22, name=j), Demo(number=17, name=e), Demo(number=16, name=i), Demo(number=15, name=h), Demo(number=12, name=a)]
```

http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/6eu172fogobv6na0mtafc9k9ol/klp8i0ttl32ip1q8ph3lk0s9bn

Comment: Ok, but how would you resolve this is the values were an Object containing 2 values - `number` and `name` f.e.? (if you want to sort on `number`)

Comment: You can use `sortedByDescending` for that like `(array1 + array2).sortedByDescending { it.number }.take(5)`

Comment: 3rd use case would be with different attribute names (not sure if `it` is still applicable then) but this will work for me.

Comment: I don't understand what you say by "different attribute names". You can return what you like in `sortedByDescending{}`. `it` is the current object.

Comment: I mean if you have 2 dataclasses. `array1` with `Demo(number, name)` and `array2` with `Demo2(id, name)`

Comment: Already, write something like `when(it) {is Demo -> {it.number} is Demo2 -> {it.id} else null} ` in sortedByDescending.

Comment: I want to add that (at least with the given examples) `array1.zip(array2) { l,r -> Math.max(l,r)}.sortedByDescending()` is also an option

Comment: @Lovis no it's wrong, you will get max of pair and not max of all. Let's try it here: http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/b81jsbes4qb6bd100pjipaoreg/59rotklqv5o7vds95lvrqs034n

Comment: @Kevinrob, whoops my bad. I should've read the expected `array3` better

Answer (score 4):

Probably this will fit your use case:

```
val c = (a + b).sortedDescending().take(5).toTypedArray()
```

Here, [`(a + b)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) creates an array with the content of `a` and `b`, then [`.sortedDescending()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-descending.html) sorts the array from maximum to minimum and puts the result into list. Then you [`.take(5)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html) top items, and then [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) converts it back to array.

---

If your class `Demo` is not [`Comparable<Demo>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/), you can:

- Implement `Comparable<T>` interface on that class to make `.sortedDescending()` applicable for it

  ```
  class Demo(...) : Comparable<Demo>{
      override fun compareTo(other: Demo): Int = number.compareTo(other.number)

      ...
  }
  ```

  Then just use the solution above.
- Use [`.sortedByDescending { }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by-descending.html) to specify how the data should be compared:

  ```
   val c = (a + b).sortedByDescending { it.number }.take(5).toTypedArray()
  ```
- Use comparators chain if you need comparison by multiple values:

  ```
   val c = (a + b)
           .sortedWith(compareBy<YourData> { it.number }.thenBy { it.name })
           .takeLast(5).reversed()
  ```

Comment: Ok, but how would you resolve this is the values were an Object containing 2 values - `number` and `name` f.e.? (if you want to sort on `number`)